# Google Fusion Tables 400 invalid_grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to use google fusion tables API from Java. I am getting `400 Bad Request` and 
`"error" : "invalid_grant"`.

I am using Service account API and OAuth2.0 to authorize my requests.

1) I have downloaded my secret key and use the below snippet for Credential.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("[[293873940759-je0f8o4j90nmqvlbl6ofbtm0492paikd@developer.gserviceaccount.com]]")


.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(KeyResources.INSTANCE.getFileFromPath("b9b48154142d235bbd711c3eb8f86bb2ec155faf-privatekey.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes("oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables")
    .build();
```

2) I am using the below code to connect to code snippet.

```
Credential credential = ServiceAccount.INSTANCE.getCredentials();
         Fusiontables fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(ServiceAccount.HTTP_TRANSPORT, ServiceAccount.JSON_FACTORY, credential)


.setApplicationName("sfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgf345q23")
         .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
         .build();

     Fusiontables.Table.List listTables = fusiontables.table().list();
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:103)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:340)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:508)
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Ganesh V

Comment: Which is the last line executed in your code before the exception is thrown?

Comment: `Fusiontables.Table.List listTables = fusiontables.table().list();`  This was the last line in the code that got executed. This calls the Credential.refreshToken. I tried calling the Credential.refreshToken directly from the code and this as well gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to remove the "[]" around your service account Id.

Apart from that, if you get 403 unauthorized error after you change the service account id, it might because that you have not grant the edit access for your table to you service account. To change the access, simply share you fusion table to you service account email and grant the "can edit" access.

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a user email, as the service account need to delegate a user account:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            ...
            .setServiceAccountUser(UserEmail)
```

and make sure the service **Fusion Tables API** is on, and in the user's owner domain console grant the correct scope to your service account:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables