# Fusion table not shown on Google Drive, while created it using Service account withFusion API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Please help on the issue, where I create a Fusion table using Google Serive Account ie using key.p12, service account email, where service account activated for Fusion table. 
( Refernce, Alejendro's great post, link: [How to authenticate in Fusion tables with Oauth v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429828/how-to-authenticate-in-fusion-tables-with-oauth-v2) )

During debug(Spring-maven project)
 - I do see the newly created table
 - Then, I insert rows data
 - Then, I see table with row data 
 - Finally, I display table with with its complete data

At this point, table is created on Google Drive.
I do see the network traffic ie xxx request/sec, meaning table is create, and I'm accessing it, hoping its created on my Google Drive, but NOT able to see it on Google Drive

So as to download table from the Google Drive to my local machine, 
I definitely like to see it on my Google Drive and then download to my local machine
I guess, table hidden under Google Drive or may be create at some other place, as network traffic shows me xxx request/sec, but not sure how to get it on the Google Drivce.

Been on this issue and hit the wall. Guru's please help...

Code as follows:

HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

```
    // check for valid setup
    if (SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL.startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.err.println(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    String p12Content = Files.readFirstLine(new File("key.p12"), Charset.defaultCharset());
    if (p12Content.startsWith("Please")) {
      System.err.println(p12Content);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // service account credential (uncomment setServiceAccountUser for domain-wide delegation)
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(FusiontablesScopes.FUSIONTABLES)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
        // .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
        .build();


    // set up global FusionTables instance
    fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    // run commands


    listTables();

    String tableId = createTable();

    insertData(tableId);

    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself. The answer is to use the drive api to share the table or transfer ownership.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing#retrieving_adding_and_manipulating_permissions

```
Permission newPermission1 = new Permission();

newPermission1.setValue('tony@acmecorp.com');
newPermission1.setType('user');
newPermission1.setRole('writer');

service.permissions().insert(tableId, newPermission1).queue(batch, callback);
```